# R: Networked Alternative to rJava/JRI?

Tags: java, r, shiny

I am a java programmer, quite new to R.

I am familiar with rJava/JRI, but would prefer a distributed networked architecture for my systems.

**TASK:**

- Java runs an NLP analysis of a text.
- It then sends an array (vector)
  of variables to R
- R analyzes the input based on a dataset in R (a
  discriminant analysis).
- R returns the output to Java (which will be
  an array of strings).

**IDEAL SOLUTION:**
My ideal solution would be as follows:

- R acts as an online webserver (perhaps shiny?) that "waits" for a
  request sent via http. (i.e., similar to a jave servlet on a
  webserver)
- Java program sends an http request with the array of variables
- R responds with a response of the class prediction.

**QUESTION:**
Is there an extant architecture in R that supports this. I expect shiny can do this, but I am hesitant to spend two or three days learning shiny unless I am confident the effort will pay off.

best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It is to use [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/apps.html) which does exactly what is described in the question.